# Static method calling another Static method with Object reference as parameter :Is It Thread Safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

i have Static Method and it is calling another static method within itself.

for example :

```
public List<Object> static first(int id){

       List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();
       list.add(a);
       list.add(b);
       list.add(c);

       //calling another static method   
       second(id,list);

       return list;

}

public String static second(int id,List<Object> listRef){

       listRef.add(a);
       listRef.add(b);
       listRef.add(c);


}
```

My Question IS:

Multiple thread is calling `public static method first(int id);` with different id.

**This is thread safe way Or Not?** As i am declaring arrayList within method And i thing it's reference may share by other threads.

> Problem is That Array Is stored in heap memory not in Individual
>   Threads Stack.So i think  sharing of Array reference by many threads
>   may happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `thread` gets its own copy of the `method`. Static methods are just methods which belong to the `Class` instead of object. As long as you are not manipulating any `shared variables` or `resources`, it is thread safe.

Comment: yes you are right but objects declared in that method are stored in Heap and not in Stack as its(stacks) size is fixed

Comment: Local variables are not directly related to heap and stack. A local int will be stored on stack while a local object will be stored on heap, with its reference on stack.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is thread-safe. Your ArrayList is a local variable and is not shared by threads (unless you explicitly do something to share it).

In this case every thread will simply have their own ArrayList.

Comment: As arraylist is stored on heap memory and  not on each threads individual stack,So i am afraid that sharing may happen?

Comment: @HarshadDeshmukh I don't understand your objetion.  What does it matter that the `ArrayList` is stored on the heap instead of the stack?  They are nonetheless referencing different `ArrayLists`, since they are from different invocations of the method.  So, there will be no sharing...

Comment: @HarshadDeshmukh there is no chance of "accidental sharing" happening. And yes, the arraylists are stored in the heap (as is true for all objects), but the references to the arraylists are stored on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

It is thread safe as long as you don't call `second` directly from each thread. To that end, you should consider making `second` a private method.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of objects are a,b & c? As this is just adding of stuff into a list and then calling another static method, I do not see any issues

So yes its thread safe..